# python smallest range from multiple lists

Tags: python, algorithm, list, range

I need to find the smallest range from a group of integer lists using at least one element from each list.

```
list1=[228, 240, 254, 301, 391]
list2=[212, 345, 395]
list3=[15, 84, 93, 103, 216, 398, 407, 488]
```

In this example the smallest range would be [391:398], because this covers the values 391, 395 and 398 from the three lists.

Each list will have at least one value and there could be many more lists

What would be the quickest computationally way to find the range?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be [391:395]?

Comment: I think (395, 398) is the smallest.

Comment: The smallest range using at least one element from each list is [391:398].  Using 391, 395, and 398

Answer (score 5):

Since your input lists are sorted, you can use a merge sort and you only need to test a range whenever the next value that is being merged in came from a different list than the last. Track the last value you've seen on each of the lists, and calculate ranges between the lowest value and the current. This is an `O(N)` linear time approach, where `N` is the total number of elements of all input lists.

The following implements that approach:

```
def smallest_range(*lists):
    iterables = [iter(it) for it in lists]
    iterable_map = {}
    for key, it in enumerate(iterables):
        try:
            iterable_map[key] = [next(it), key, it]
        except StopIteration:
            # empty list, won't be able to find a range
            return None
    lastvalues, lastkey = {}, None
    candidate, candidatediff = None, float('inf')

    while iterable_map:
        # get the next value in the merge sort
        value, key, it = min(iterable_map.values())
        lastvalues[key] = value

        if len(lastvalues) == len(lists) and lastkey != key:
            minv = min(lastvalues.values())
            difference = value - minv
            if candidatediff > difference:
                candidate, candidatediff = (minv, value), difference
        lastkey = key

        try:
            iterable_map[key][0] = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            # this iterable is empty, remove it from consideration
            del iterable_map[key]

    return candidate
```

Demo:

```
>>> list1 = [228, 240, 254, 301, 391]
>>> list2 = [212, 345, 395]
>>> list3 = [15, 84, 93, 103, 216, 398, 407, 488]
>>> smallest_range(list1, list2, list3)
(391, 398)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution slows down significantly as the lists get large/many but it doesn't assume the input lists are presorted:

```
from itertools import product

def smallest_range(*arrays):

    result = min((sorted(numbers) for numbers in product(*arrays)), key=lambda n: abs(n[0] - n[-1]))

    return (result[0], result[-1])

list1 = [228, 240, 254, 301, 391]
list2 = [212, 345, 395]
list3 = [15, 84, 93, 103, 216, 398, 407, 488]

print(smallest_range(list1, list2, list3))
```

**USAGE:**

```
list1 = [228, 240, 254, 301, 391]
list2 = [212, 345, 395]
list3 = [15, 84, 93, 103, 216, 398, 407, 488]

print(smallest_range(list1, list2, list3))
```

**PRINTS:**

(391, 398)

Comment: Why use `sorted()` when you could use `min()` instead? And the `abs(numbers[0] - numbers[-1])` should really just be a `key` function to `min()`. Still, this is incredibly inefficient as the number of products scales exponentially with the number of elements in the lists (as well as the number of lists).

Comment: If the numbers are not sorted, it's easy (and cheap) to sort them before passing them into my approach, giving a `O(NlogN)` solution.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I wasn't aware of min() having a key function.  Thank you for the heads up, I've shorted my code accordingly.  I believe I acknowledged its inefficient nature in my first sentence.  I wanted to demonstrate that the basic problem isn't overly complex -- even with the newly added constraint!